# How to detect where your code is running (Mathematica, Engine, CDF, the Wolfram Cloud, etc.)?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I'd like to include logic to avoid breaking my functions in different environments, like the cloud (which lacks support for many things) or the wolfram engine, or CDF. For example, I'd like a test:

```
If[!$RunningInCloud, Print @ SystemInformation[]]
```

Since `SystemInformation` is not supported in the cloud, what would `$RunningInCloud` be?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`$CloudEvaluation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$CloudEvaluation).

Comment: Duplicate of: [Detect if code is running in the cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91202/detect-if-code-is-running-in-the-cloud)

Comment: What about the other possibilities: whether it’s in the engine, command line, or subkernel

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m also looking for - a unified answer

Comment: This is not a duplicate question and should be reopened. It is nontrivial to detect if code is running in PlayerPro, or Kernel-only without a Notebook-Frontend. I have struggled with this in the past.

Comment: See [How useful is $EvaluationEnvironment?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116419/5478) and linked topics.